# Sending dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is the result of a query and I want to slice it and transform to a list.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
  Name Age Weight
0 Cat   5   35
1 Dog   6   25
```

Here is what I got:
The query:

```
def queryMyQuery(params):
    data = pd.read_sql(sql=queryMyQuery, con=engine)
    return data.to_json()
```

And this how I slice the dataframe and make a list:

```
df=data
df['Names']= data['Name'].tolist()
```

The problem is that I am getting an error saying  string indices must be integers, not str.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure if understand - do you need `df['Names']= df['Name'].values.tolist()` ?

Comment: maybe he just needs the list, in which case everything on the left side of that would disappear, I guess the question isn't clear enough

Comment: I need to get the list of values like: [u'dog', u'cat']. Yes @aws_apprentice you are right I could use names = data['Name'].values.tolist(). The problem it's that it's saying that TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You're trying to reference `data` outside of your function - it probably doesn't mean what you think it does at that point.

Comment: Ciao @asongtoruin I did a print when trying to reference to data and it's as I thought(the dataframe). So something else must be the problem